# Negative Margins, Hack or Not?

Tags: css, web-standards

I've come across various posts where people are stating that negative margins are hacks. Thus I've strayed away from using them with exception to particular cases when I can justifiably use them, like throwing text off the screen with `margin:-9999px`

Question, are negative margins a hack and when is it right to use negative margins? I've seen them used in the 960 Grid System with, `.push` and `.pull`, any other cases where they are justifiably usable?!?!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Negative margins are allowed based on [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties). I have used them to let things overhang their container.

Comment: I'm out of votes, but conformance with W3C specs is one of the most important arguments...

Comment: Underlined by the comparison of the specifications of margins and borders (which cannot be negative)

Answer (score 12):

I would argue it's not a hack: It's defined, logical behaviour; it's supported in all browsers; it can be expected to be supported in future versions of browsers (the absence of future support is the most important argument against hacks).

Also, as @durilai points out, they are officially sanctioned (although with limits) by the W3C.

This [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) supports the case.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect they've been labeled as a hack because of inconsistent browser behavior.

Whenever possible I use `position: relative` and negative top and left values to pull elements into new locations.  This isn't possible for every case, but I find it behaves more consistently in all the Internet Explorer flavors.

Comment: @Tomas this one jumps out: http://haslayout.net/css/Negative-Margin-Bug.  Mainly what I'm getting at is that to use them, you generally have to apply another hack to get consistent display in IE6/7.  This doesn't necessarily label the negative margin as a hack, but has given me enough reason to avoid using them whenever possible.  I've found the easiest way to get x-browser display is to rely on rock solid, simple CSS (position and floats with width defined).

Comment: +1 for relative positioning. Setting position:relative; can magically fix other bugs as well.

Comment: The problem is that relative positioning does *not* affect the elements following, whereas negative margins do.  This is the crucial difference between the two.