# How can margin input after rowspan td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to achieve something very simple like below, In my code, you can see, In `td` I set `rowspan="2"` and put an `input "id = image"`. I am trying to have the image below the `input` field.

```html
<style>
    table tr {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;
    }
    table tr td {
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .image{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .image-input{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<table style="width:400px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="CId"></td>
            <td>Contries </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Contries"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="image">image</td>
            <td rowspan="2"><input class="image-input" type="text">
                <img style="width:100px;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/80bfb4acb1a216227bc46762c3415862?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Branch</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Brand"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you explain, why do you need `rowspan=2`?

Comment: @Ayush Bahuguna: because i will display an image below input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect by **[floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)** the image to the left, and also making use of a **[negative margin](http://css-101.org/negative-margin/index.php)** of the same height as the input fields (which is `16px` by default):

```
.image-input {
  margin-top: -16px;
  float: left;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;
}

table tr td {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.image {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -16px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Category</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="CId"></td>
      <td>Contries </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Contries"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="image">image</td>
      <td rowspan="2"><input class="image-input" type="text">
        <img src="/" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Branch</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Brand"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You obviously know more than me but is negative margin a really good solution. I mean I say this, from personal experience that negative margins don't work well cross-browser.

Comment: Not sure on your past experiences, but negative margins should [**work fine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534362/2341603) on all browsers. According to [**Smashing Magazine**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/), "negative margins are wholly supported across all modern browsers (and IE6 in most cases)." Considering most people don't even worry about supporting IE7, you're pretty much good to go ;) It's not even bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684917/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-or-padding-in-css

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a line break `<br>` after the `.image-input`. Give some bottom margin to it, and it fits perfectly.

```html
<style>
    table tr {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;
    }
    table tr td {
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .image{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .image-input{
        margin:0;
        margin-bottom: 2px; // or whatever your heart desires
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="CId"></td>
            <td>Contries </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Contries"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="image">image</td>
            <td rowspan="2"><input class="image-input" type="text"> <br>
                <img src="/" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Branch</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Brand"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution.

I've used `position: absolute;` & `top: 6px` for `input class="image-input"` and given `position: relative` to the `parent td`.

```html
<style>
    table tr {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #E8E8E8;
    }
    table tr td {
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .image{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .rowspan {
       position: relative;
    }
    .image-input{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="CId"></td>
            <td>Contries </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Contries"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="image">image</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="rowspan"><input class="image-input" type="text">
                <img src="/" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Branch</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Brand"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.